# how can i solve this error when trirng to install dukto?

Tags: 20.04

i did it by this command

```
sudo apt-get install dukto


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dukto
```

Comment: I don't know what that package is, but I don't see it available for any supported release of Ubuntu; where did you get the name from?  eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=dukto  though I used a terminal search which includes ESM releases as well

Comment: I'd look for alternatives. Most recent version is 6 years old. https://sourceforge.net/projects/dukto/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dukto is not found in any of the regular Ubuntu repositories, but you have a couple of options to get it installed:

1. Download it [from the home page](http://www.msec.it/blog/?page_id=11), then install the `.deb` with the following command:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i dukto_6.0-1_amd64.deb
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to be in the same directory as the `.deb` file if you plan on installing the package this way.*
2. Add the source repository to your installation, *then* install it:

   ```
   sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dukto.list"
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install dukto
   ```

#### However, ...

Be warned that `dukto` has not been updated in several years:

[image: Dukto Versions]

The most recent release is for Ubuntu 16.04, which is in its last month of support. If you really must use this package, you may want to run it from an Ubuntu 16.04 installation that is contained in a virtual machine. This will ensure the host system is secured with up-to-date security fixes and installation of the `dukto` package works because it is isolated in a VM.

Comment: thanks the installation finished and outed this

 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dukto:
 dukto depends on libqt4-declarative (>= 4:4.7.0~rc1); however:
  Package libqt4-declarative is not installed.
 dukto depends on libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3); however:
  Package libqt4-network is not installed.
 dukto depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1); however:
  Package libqtcore4 is not installed.
 dukto depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.6.1); however:
  Package libqtgui4 is not installed.

Comment: dpkg: error processing package dukto (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dukto

Comment: but the dukto icon appears and it doesn't run

Comment: If you installed the application on a version of Ubuntu newer than 16.04, errors would be expected 

Answer (score 0):

However, the official support is only until 16.04 - 18.04, for later versions, it does not work, such as 20.04 or 21.04.

1 - `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa` [ dependences]

2 - Download deb from https://sourceforge.net/projects/dukto/files/

3- dpkg -i xxxx.deb